# How to get data from model provider which calls a webservice

Tags: web-services, angularjs

I want to retrieve data from a model provider, but all I am getting got is 'undefined' in my controller.

Here is the code:

**Controller**:

```
pdmAtWeb.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, ItemModel){
$scope.updateTableFromSearch = function(){
        $scope.myData = ItemModel.findAllItems();
        console.log($scope.myData);
};});
```

**Provider**

```
pdmAtWeb.provider('ItemModel', function () {
this.defaultEndpoint = '/item';
this.defaultServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/webservice';

this.setDefaultEndpoint = function (newEndpoint) {
    this.defaultEndpoint = newEndpoint;
};

this.setDefaultServiceUrl = function (newServiceUrl) {
    this.defaultServiceUrl = newServiceUrl;
}

this.$get = function ($http) {
    var endpoint = this.endpoint;
    var serviceUrl = this.serviceUrl;

    var refreshConnection = function () {
        // reconnect
    }
    return{
        findAllItems: function () {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: serviceUrl + endpoint}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;

                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                });
        }
    }
}});
```

The provider "ItemModel" receives the correct data from the web service. Perhaps this is an async problem, but I'm not sure.

**UPDATE**

After adding a deferred/promise implementation it works as expected. Here is the final code:

**Controller**:

```
pdmAtWeb.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, ItemModel){
$scope.updateTableFromSearch = function(){
       ItemModel.findAllItems().then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
           $scope.myData = data;
       });
};
});
```

**Provider**

```
pdmAtWeb.provider('ItemModel', function () {
    this.defaultEndpoint = '/item';
    this.defaultServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/webservice';

    this.setDefaultEndpoint = function (newEndpoint) {
        this.defaultEndpoint = newEndpoint;
    };

    this.setDefaultServiceUrl = function (newServiceUrl) {
        this.defaultServiceUrl = newServiceUrl;
    }

    this.$get = function ($http, $q) {
        var endpoint = this.defaultEndpoint;
        var serviceUrl = this.defaultServiceUrl;

        var refreshConnection = function () {
            // reconnect
        }
        return{
            findAllItems: function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                 $http({method: 'GET', url: serviceUrl + endpoint}).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                     deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      deferred.reject();
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a deferred to accomplish this. Your `$http` already returns a promise. In your first example, the reason you are getting an undefined is because you are not returning anything. Check your `findAllItems` . It is not returning anything.

If you do `return $http.get(.....)` everything should work without using deferred explicitly.

Here is the corrected version :

```
pdmAtWeb.provider('ItemModel', function () {
this.defaultEndpoint = '/item';
this.defaultServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/webservice';

this.setDefaultEndpoint = function (newEndpoint) {
    this.defaultEndpoint = newEndpoint;
};

this.setDefaultServiceUrl = function (newServiceUrl) {
    this.defaultServiceUrl = newServiceUrl;
}

this.$get = function ($http) {
    var endpoint = this.endpoint;
    var serviceUrl = this.serviceUrl;

    var refreshConnection = function () {
        // reconnect
    }
    return{
        findAllItems: function () {
            //NOTE addition of return below.
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: serviceUrl + endpoint}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //NOTE: YOU SHOULD ALSO return data here for it to work.  
                    return data;

                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                });
        }
    }
}});
```